# Hidden field in spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I wanted to use Spring MVC hidden tag in below code. Is this possible in below code, what I have to write in my controller to do that or what I am doing is correct.

```xml
    <c:forEach var="record" items="${records}">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form:form id="myForm" action="list.html" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="record" value="${record}" />
                    <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('myForm').submit();">Submit</a> 
                </form:form>
            </td>
        </tr>
     </c:forEach>
```

Any help will be highly appriciated.

Comment: is your question whether and how you can bind that field back to the form?

Comment: Yes, I think, You can see that here I am using for loop and hidden variable will be populated with runtime of loop so if I use <form:hidden path="record"> then I think record won't populate. so my question is what I have to write in my controller so that it binds with the values I am fetching from loop.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are on the right track [depending on what your backing bean is], but in order to bind an ID as a hidden field *on submission* automatically to a "Person" bean (in this example), you would do something like:

```
<c:forEach var="person" items="${persons}" varStatus="status">
    <tr>
        <c:set var="personFormId" value="person${status.index}"/>
        ....
        <form id="${personFormId}" action="${deleteUrl}" method="POST">
            <input id="id" name="id" type="hidden" value="${person.id}"/>
        </form>

        <td>${person.firstName}</td>
        <td>${person.lastName}</td>
        .... 
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

In case you'd like to *render* a hidden field, you would use a `form:hidden` tag:

```
<form:hidden path="id" />
```

Take a look at [Hidden Input Tag](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-jsp-formtaglib-hiddeninputtag) section of the Spring docs.

Answer (score 2):

In the rest of this answer, substitute "delete" and "deteted" with the operation you are attempting to implement.  for example "exploded", "bitten", or "edited"

The JSP code you posted has several issues.

1. no close tag for the `<td>` element.
2. your form is posting to "items.html".  This seems to be an html page.  If so, your form action is 0% correct.
3. every form has the same id, so the `getElementById()` call can never work.
4. `href="#"` will cause your page to scroll to the top when the user clicks the link.
5. You do not identify, to the user, the record to be deleted.

Here is what I think you want:

```
<c:forEach var="record" items="${records}">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form:form method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="activity" value="delete"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="record" value="${record}"/>
                <a href="javascript:this.form.submit()">Delete ${record}</a>
            </form:form>
        <td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

The snippet will post to the current spring controller.  Two fields are included in the post: "activity" which identifies this as a delete and "record" which identifies the record to be deleted.  Based on your needs, add `action="some url"` to the `form:form` tag.

Answer (score 2):

I think I solved the problem. If I write input tag like this

```
<form:hidden path="id" value="${record}" />
```

in this way I can reassign the value of hidden variable but when I look into the rendered html code its like this

```
<input type="hidden" value="0" name="record" value="10"/>
```

generate the value attribute twice and takes the value I wanted which is 10.But it solves my problem. If anyone has further comments on this then that will be appreciated.

Comment: Using Spring 1.4.0 and the it renders `<input id="id" name="id" value="4" type="hidden" value="0"/>`

Comment: I think it won't be the solution. It takes the data from the second attribute Value=''10", But in latest version of Spring the rendered HTML code is like <input id="id" name="id" value="4" type="hidden" value="0"/>. In this case your controller method will get 0 as value.